# Jenkins job that calls cyclically a script

Tags: jenkins

I'm having some difficulties in getting this one working. 
How would I have to configure a job in Jenkins to call some script on a node, the node to execute and when exiting, the job to not declare the build finished but to wait for a certain amount of time and to call again the script. The waiting period would have to be dynamically calculated at runtime based on a target start time. Such a build would have to be stopped by some user input and not by aborting the build.

I know pipelining might be needed in this case but I'm not very sure how the build history would look like as I intend to have only one build appearing in there not a bunch of builds spawned by the main one. Hopefully, I was able to make myself easy to understand.

Thank you very much.

Comment: i think we need more info to answer your question properly
 - what does your script do?
 - how long your job will be "idle"

Comment: @hopetds, I'm trying to configure a Jenkins job that triggers and manages the results of some regression testing activity on a node that usually takes longer than a day. On top of this, the node involved is being used for debugging purposes during the day so the regressions would have to run during the night. This is the reason of having this waiting time as it cannot interfere with the testers during the day. The script on the node calls for tests that are using some hardware equipment.

Comment: if you want to use jenkins to manage this scripts i can suggest you to monitor periodically: if your test script finished successfully( some flag or exit code) - job finishes with success. if script finished with errors/aborted/any action that you don't want  - job finishes with error.  If i understand you correctly...